# Can Skyrim be run on Linux Mint 12?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just installed Linux Mint 12 on my computer and was considering buying Skyrim. Would I be able to run Skyrim on my computer?

Comment: as mint is build on top of ubuntu, you should search for skyrim and ubuntu instead of mint (since the mint community isnt as big)... But by using wine it should be possible, still I'd advice just running an xp or windows7 dualboot

Comment: I currently am using a dual boot so that's probably what I'll do. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Some](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XOxJG9VCHSY) [people](http://gentoolinux.cyacomputerblog.com/2011/11/16/watch-the-elder-scrolls-skyrim-linux-ultra-settings-with-sound/) have had some success running it under Wine, but as with trying to run most games on OSes for which they weren't designed, you're likely to have issues that the makers of the game aren't going to be able to help you with.  Sometimes things go smoothly, but it's almost guaranteed to be tricky and require some technical expertise and a willingness to tweak.